# Eclipse : edittext changed listener , edittext length to spinner item

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, listener

I have this code:

```
public class SentSMSActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnSend;
    private EditText etPlain, etCipher, etDest, key2;
    private String plaintext, tempCipher = null, ciphertext = "";
    private int keyRF, keyCaesar;
    private CheckBox cbEncrypt;
    private String dest, msgSend;
    private Spinner sp;
    private String numbers[];
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sentsms_activity);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSent);
        etPlain = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlainSent);
        etDest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestSent);
        key2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKey2Sent);
        cbEncrypt = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEnc);
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spKey1);
        //      String numbers[] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        //              "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19",
        //              "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25" };

        key2.setEnabled(false);
        keyRF = 2;

        final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,
                    int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1,
                    int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                for (int k = 0; k < etPlain.length() - 1; k++) {
                    numbers[k] = String.valueOf(k);
                }
            }
        };

        //third, we must add the textWatcher to our EditText

        sp.setClickable(false);
        cbEncrypt
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        if (cbEncrypt.isChecked()) {
                            key2.setEnabled(true);
                            sp.setClickable(true);
                            etPlain.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    SentSMSActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    numbers);
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            sp.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {
                            key2.setText("");
                            key2.setEnabled(false);
                            sp.setClickable(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to make a spinner with numbers from the `edittext` string, however when run it give an error like this:

```
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:47)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:169)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:125)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.hery.androidkripto.SentSMSActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(SentSMSActivity.java:97)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-06 20:02:21.205: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm very confused with the error and have been trying to solve it for 3 hours with no progress, so I hope some members can give me a solution.
***Problem: spinner with numbers item from the edittext string length***

**Answer thanks to user vetal-lebed:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private EditText et;
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++){
            list.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

}

and thanks to other member aswell

Comment: check if numbers array is not null

Comment: it shdnt be null if edittext filled right?

Comment: debug your code to find out which line give you NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't  allocate memory for your array "numbers". You should do following :

```
numbers = new String[0];
```

And in your afterTextChanged() method you should create new Array with needed length (You can take it from editable). And then you can initialize all of elements of array and call notifyDataSetChanged() from adapter.

**UPD**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private EditText et;
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++){
            list.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: it works for error, but why spinner still empty when i input something in edittext?

Comment: After loop which initializes elements of array you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
         
       numbers = new String[etPlain.length()-1];
       for(int k=0;k<etPlain.length()-1;k++)
       {
        numbers[k]=String.valueOf(k);
       }
       Log.d("number",String.valueOf(numbers.length));
                  
      }   // new textwatcher

Comment: etPlain.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SentSMSActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);       
       sp.setAdapter(adapter); //after notifyDatasetchanged, spinner still empty, still null pointer exception

Comment: I don't know what you need. But see my UPD. It is something like you need.

Comment: wow thank you! gonna try. can i ask why prefer arraylist? instead normal string array?

Comment: because ArrayList is dynamically allocated array. So You doesn't changes link on object when creates new array with new length and doesn't need make a lot of code for adapter to inform  it about new array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24030/discussion-between-trutone-and-vetal-lebed)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like numbers hasn't been initialised prior to calling onCheckedChange()

Answer (score 0):

Use following code when initialize arrays

ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

Comment: You need to initialize your arrayadapter before .Please refer code     .ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        
        String[] items = { "Milk", "Butter", "Yogurt", "Toothpaste", "Ice Cream" };
        
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);